# Is there a way to find out if an element has a scrollbar on it using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Let say I have an element like so

```
<div id="myDiv" style="height:10px; width:100px; overflow:scroll;"> 
   random amount of lorem ipsum... 
</div>
```

Is there a way in JS or Jquery to look at $("#myDiv") and see if it has scrollbars?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work

```
$.fn.hasVerticalScrollBar = function () {
     return this[0].clientHeight < this[0].scrollHeight;
}

$.fn.hasHorizontalScrollBar = function () {
    return this[0].clientWidth < this[0].scrollWidth;
}
```

Usage

```
alert($('#mydivid').hasHorizontalScrollBar());
alert($('#mydivid').hasVerticalScrollBar());
```

**EDIT:**

To use this method with *invisible* element, clone the div, set its opacity to 0, append the clone to the body, check if the clone has the scroll bar and then remove the clone:

```
var clone = $('#mydivid').clone();
clone.css('opacity', '0').appendTo('body');
if (clone.hasHorizontalScrollBar()) {
   //do the job here
}
clone.remove();
```

Comment: Fixed a couple of typos for you. +1 for an excellent answer, though [this may play up in Opera](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36).

Comment: @lonesomeday  well I hit most of the browsers...Opera is a minor share of the market

Comment: This will not work when div is not visible on the page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637577/how-to-obtain-clientwidth-clientheight-before-div-is-visible.

To solve this problem i cloned my div, set its opacity to 0, append the clone to the body, check if the clone has the scroll bar and then remove the clone.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the text in another div, and compare the width/height of that one with `#myDiv`. If it's taller, there is a scrollbar:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="..."> 
    <div id="inner">random amount of lorem ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

Example:

```
if( $('#inner').height() > $('#myDiv').height() ){
  alert('vertical scrollbar');
}

if( $('#inner').width() > $('#myDiv').width() ){
  alert('horizontal scrollbar');
}
```

Comment: .. This wouldnt work if there was padding or margins on the inner div, because mydiv would always be greater.