# clientWidth of bootstrap modal returns 0

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal having id `myModal`.

In my javascript when i do something like

```
window.onload = function(){
         var container = document.getElementById("myModal");
         console.log(container.clientWidth);
}
```

It shows `0`.
How to get the clientWidth of a Bootstrap modal before it is opened?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery `width` works just fine

```
$('#ModalName').find('.modal-dialog').width()
```

For `$('#ModalName')` you are always getting wrong value.

Comment: Well what do you know. jQuery works. But any idea as to why pure JS clientWidth is not working?

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height) there is discussion abouth the same problem in comments for accepted answer. Maybe it will be usefull for you.

Comment: More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841124/find-the-potential-width-of-a-hidden-element) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637577/how-to-obtain-clientwidth-clientheight-before-div-is-visible).